# Read Custom User profile Property in Sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, people-picker

In O365 I have create site column for User Profile (eg.`DaysOfWorks`). I have mapped this column with `RefinableString00` managed property.

I want to display that column in Search result webpart Using Display Template. How can this be done?

Comment: run the crawl and it will then come up in search results.

Answer (score 0):

here in short a description, what you have to do:

First, go into your search service application and open the search Schema. Make sure, that your site column is a manage property and run a crawl.

The second step is the modification of the display template. You find this file under master pages and can modify it to Display your value.